# Collecting points in a density plot

Tags: plotting

I have the following density plot:

```
DensityPlot[x^2 + y^2, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1} , MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> 1]
```

I want to collect the points on the level curve z=1 shown by the mesh on the graph.

thanks for your help

[image]

Comment: If `g` is your plot you could just use the output as in `ListPlot[Select[g[[1, 1]], 0.99 <= [[1]]^2 + #[[2]]^2 <= 1.01 &]]`.

Comment: Try `Cases[Normal[(* plot *)], _Line, Infinity]` and report back…

Comment: @b.gatessucks Thank you very much, it works.

Comment: @J.M. This method works too. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

The following is just for the sake of entering an answer to this question that has been otherwise answered in comments.

Let's store your plot:

```
g = DensityPlot[x^2 + y^2, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1} , MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> 1]
```

---

[@J.M.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/j-m) suggested extracting the `Line` object representing the contour line directly from the plot, which is the more straightforward approach in my opinion:

```
contour = First@Cases[Normal[g], _Line, Infinity]
```

> `{Line[{{0.0714286, -0.997354}, {-2.22045*10^-16, -1.}, [...], {0.0714286, -0.997354}}]}`

This returns a `Line` object, which can be visualized directly using `Graphics`, or from which coordinates can be extracted.

```
Graphics[contour]
contour[[1]]
```

[image: JM]

> `{{0.0714286, -0.997354}, {-2.22045*10^-16, -1.}, [...], {0.0714286, -0.997354}}`

---

Alternatively, [@b.gatessucks](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/134/b-gatessucks) suggested using a `Select` statement to extract points that belong to the circle.

Note that a `#` had gone missing in the comment; I would also suggest adding `AspectRatio -> Automatic` to the `ListPlot` to make sure that circles are plotted as such, rather than deformed (`AspectRatio` otherwise defaults to `1/GoldenRatio` for the plotting functions):

```
ListPlot[
 Select[g[[1, 1]], 0.99 <= #[[1]]^2 + #[[2]]^2 <= 1.01 &],
 AspectRatio -> Automatic
]
```

[image: b.gates]